# Array manipulation: adding elements

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to programming, and I just learned about array. However, in one of the quiz questions, I can't figure out why my answer is wrong. I tried to explain my thinking.

The question is:

```
    int[] b = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int[] c = b;
    c[0] += b[2];
    c[1] += b[1];
    c[2] += b[0];
    System.out.println(c[0] + c[1] + c[2]);
```

My thinking is although array is a reference type, int[] c = b can still be treated as

```
int [] c = { 1, 2, 3 }; // the same as int [] b

c[0] += b[2] means c[0] = c[0] + b[2] = 1 + 3 = 4
c[1] += b[1] means c[1] = c[1] + b[1] = 2 + 2 = 4
c[2] += b[0] means c[2] = c[2] + b[0] = 3 + 1 = 4
```

So I thought that the output is 12. However, the answer is 15.

I am so sorry for asking such a basic question, but I was wondering if anyone can help me understand how to come up with 15. Thank you so much!

Comment: It’s not a basic question >:( you shouldn’t feel bad for asking questions! Coding can be very hard  and the only way to progress is to ask and learn. Just by taking the effort to ask a question, trust me, you’re already better than like 50% of others who do cs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support and encouragement! I really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 2):

actually java copies arrays by their references not values.
so in the last line of your code, b[0] is changed to 4 so

```
c[2] += b[0] means c[2] = c[2] + b[0] = 3 + 4 = 7
```

so your output is 15.
If you want to copy an array without reference,you can do this:

```
int[] c = Arrays.copyOf(b, b.length);
```

now, your output should be 12.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I read the book and learned that java copes arrays by their references not values, but I don't really understand what it means. I did not know that both arrays will update to the same values.

Answer (score 2):

As `c` and `b` refer to the same array, when `c[0]` is changed to 4, it means that `b[0]` is also 4.  Thus, the result of `c[2] += b[0]` is `3 + 4 = 7`, and the total sum of all elements is `4 + 4 + 7 = 15`.

Assigning a reference to array `int[] c = b;` creates just an alias and it does NOT create a new instance of the array as in the case of its copying (using methods [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-), [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-int:A-int-int-), [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-)) or cloning `int[] c = b.clone();`

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! I did not know that both arrays will change at the same time. I thought only int [] c will change, and int [] b will not.

Answer (score 2):

Since you set `c = b`, this means that whatever changes you make onto `c` will be reflected onto `b` and vice verca, since they reference the same array. If you wanted `b` and `c` to be separate arrays, you should use `Arrays.copy()`.

For your problem, we can now go step by step to analyze how the values change during each step:

```
int[] b = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] c = b;

c[0] += b[2];
//c[0] = c[0] + b[2] = 1 + 3 = 4
//b[0] = 4
// b and c = {4, 2, 3}

c[1] += b[1];
//c[1] = c[1] + b[1] = 2 + 2 = 4
//b[1] = 4
//b and c = {4, 4, 3}

c[2] += b[0];
//c[2] = c[2] + b[0] = 3 + 4 = 7
//b[2] = 7
//b and c = {4, 4, 7}
System.out.println(c[0] + c[1] + c[2]);
//4 + 4 + 7 = 15 :)
```

I hope this helped! Please let me know if you need any further clarification or details :)

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing such detailed explanations! The first part of your answers is really what I need to know. It cleared my mind! :)

Comment: No problem. Yeah, this problem would have been very confusing if you didn’t know that one detail lol

Answer (score 1):

The last statement ( c[2] + b[0]) will generate 7 and not 4 because b[0] has been updated to 4 in the first statement
[image]

then output will be 4 + 4+ 7 which is 15.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing the detailed steps. This is really helpful!

Comment: @user13966876 please mark it as correct if this helped :)